# D3 tooltip error: "Cannot read property '-1' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm trying to create a tooltip like this one: http://bl.ocks.org/sdbernard/2e44bd82c9d048b88451/2b31b98b8f6acb8d7c6026b5eec801e2f1f61ab2

The underlying code and data structure of that block is similar to that of my own, except that I'm also doing small multiples. Here's my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BsLMhbldIYvZEVOu23aM?p=preview

When I try to adapt the block's tooltip to my visualization, using month and year — or even just the year (as in the original) — I get the error message: "Cannot read property '-1' of undefined"

The problematic code seems to be here:

```
              var mousex = d3.mouse(this);
              mousex = mousex[0] + 10;
              var invertedx = xScale.invert(mousex);

// This doesn't work:  //
                invertedx = invertedx.dates;   
                var selected = (d.value);
                mousedate = dates.indexOf(String(invertedx));
                pro = d.value[mousedate].y;
```

This also doesn't work:

```
            invertedx = invertedx.getMonth() + invertedx.getFullYear();
            var selected = (d.value);
            for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
                dates[k] = selected[k].x
                dates[k] = dates[k].getMonth() + dates[k].getFullYear();
            }

            mousedate = dates.indexOf(invertedx);
            pro = d.value[mousedate].y;
```

Here's my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BsLMhbldIYvZEVOu23aM?p=preview
I've spent almost a week on this, without much or any progress. In advance, thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've been able to find so far is if you do console.log(d) right before the problem area, you don't have a d.value defined. What I'm seeing instead is d.values, which is an array.

Also mousedate ends up as -1 because there isn't an index in dates that it's looking for.

I probably haven't found the whole solution, but fixing that should help get you back on track a bit, at least.

Comment: Thanks; I've changed it to "d.values" -- Could you clarify how to resolve the absence of an index in dates?

Comment: It looks like you're assigning invertedx twice and that the second one (under the doesn't work comment) is undefined. So you won't be able to find the indexOf it. To debug it, I recommend printing out console.log lines for all the variables you're looking at and seeing the console output in Chrome Developer Tools. That's what I'm doing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing the same; so far the only valid output I've received has been from `console.log(dates)` `console.log(dates[0])` `console.log(dataset[0].values[0].x);` and `console.log(dataset[0].values[0].y);`

Comment: Hmm the other thing I'm noticing is invertedx (the first time it's assigned) seems to be making years that are larger than startDate and endDate. It has years like 2019, but your end date is 2017. I think if you figure out the correct invertedx assignment, it'll help a lot.

Comment: I've made a lot of progress: I'm getting mostly correct dates and values returned in console.log. I think the strange dates on the larger, "main" chart might have to do with its size, which may also be related to the error message i'm getting for the tooltip itself: `Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null`. Any insight?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help in getting back on track! After a lot of fiddling around in the console, I managed to pass both the dates and values through to the tool tip. You saved my weekend.
For reference, here's the solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qo90unX6OnVpl1zvcEjw?p=preview

Comment: awesome! you're welcome @LaissezPasser and I hope you have a great weekend